# HTML5 camera does not switch off after route change in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, video, camera, angularjs

I'm testing the video capabilities of HTML5. With a directive `userMedia`, I'm able to switch on my camera on my MacBook via [`navigator.getUserMedia()`](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) (actually via an adapter to make it cross browser - at least those who support it).

But when I change my `$route`, I don't see myself anymore (hurray), but the camera does not switch off (the green light stays on). Only refreshing the page resets everything (which is normal).

I was hoping that watching for a change in `$location.path()` would do the trick:

```
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ...
            var path = $location.path();
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return $location.path();
            }, function(value) {
                if (value && value !== path) {
                    $log.info('Location changed, switching off camera');
                    webRTCAdapter.detachMediaStream(elm[0]);
                }
            }, true);
        }
```

**detachMediaStream (Chrome):**

```
    webRTCAdapter.detachMediaStream = function(element) {
        console.log("Detaching media stream");
        element.pause();
        element.src = '';
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    };
```

**Html:**

```
<video id="localVideo" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" user-media="user-media"></video>
```

`detachMediaStream` gets executed (I see the necessary logs in `console.log`), but the camera does not switch off.

**Any idea how to solve this? Should I unload the element somehow?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. The [`LocalMediaStream`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/webrtc/LocalMediaStream) which was created when the camera switches on, needs to be stopped by using the `stop()` function.

A reference to the created `LocalMediaStream` object has to be kept, when attaching it to the video element:

```
 controller: function($element) {
            var self = this;
            self.onUserMediaSuccess = function(stream) {
                $log.info("User has granted access to local media.");
                webRTCAdapter.attachMediaStream($element[0], stream);

                // keep a reference
                self.localStream = stream;
            };
```

This `LocalMediaStream` reference has to added to `detachMediaStream` function, when the `$destroy` event occurs (thank you for that, [**Joseph Silber**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825568/joseph-silber)):

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   $log.info('Location changed, switching off camera');
   webRTCAdapter.detachMediaStream( elm[0], ctrl.localStream);
});
```

On the `LocalMediaStream` object I need to execute the `stop()` function:

```
    webRTCAdapter.detachMediaStream = function(element, stream) {
        console.log("Detaching media stream");
        element.pause();
        element.src = '';
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

        // stopping stream (camera, ...)
        stream.stop();
    };
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This code works pretty good in Opera. To turn off my camera LED I have to restart Chrome window(when LED is on webcam is not accessible for other applications).

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76 m

Comment: That actually helped me to successfully remove a html5 video element on scope destruction! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, we already support element.mozSrcObject = stream (to become element.srcObject, and which Chrome should have soon though I don't know if they'll prefix it for the time being).  That makes it easier to handle since you don't *need* to keep a second reference to it.  (element.mozSrcObject.stop(); element.mozSrcObject = null)