# Stop/Close webcam using getUserMedia and RTCPeerConnection Chrome 25

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

I'm on Chrome 25 successfully using getUserMedia and RTCPeerConnection to connect audio from a web page to another party, but I'm unable to get the API to stop the red blinking indication icon in the Chrome tab that media is being used on that page.  My question is essentially a duplicate of [Stop/Close webcam which is opened by navigator.getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642926/stop-close-webcam-which-is-opened-by-navigator-getusermedia) except that the resolution there isn't working.  If I have a page that just uses getUserMedia with no remote media (no peer), then stopping the camera turns off the blinking tab indicator.  Adding remote streams seems to be a/the issue.  Here's what I've currently got for my "close" code:

```
if (localStream) {
    if (peerConnection && peerConnection.removeStream) {
        peerConnection.removeStream(localStream);
    }
    if (localStream.stop) {
        localStream.stop();
    }
    localStream.onended = null;
    localStream = null;
}
if (localElement) {
    localElement.onerror = null;
    localElement.pause();
    localElement.src = undefined;
    localElement = null;
}
if (remoteStream) {
    if (peerConnection && peerConnection.removeStream) {
        peerConnection.removeStream(remoteStream);
    }
    if(remoteStream.stop) {
        remoteStream.stop();
    }
    remoteStream.onended = null;
    remoteStream = null;
}
if (remoteElement) {
    remoteElement.onerror = null;
    remoteElement.pause();
    remoteElement.src = undefined;
    remoteElement = null;
}
if (peerConnection) {
    peerConnection.close();
    peerConnection = null;
}
```

I've tried with and without the `removeStream()` call, I've tried with and without the `stop()` call, I've tried the `element.src=""` and `element.src=null`, I'm running out of ideas.  Anyone know if this is a bug or user/my error in the use of the API?

**EDIT:** I set my default device (using Windows) to a camera that has a light when it's in use, and upon stopping, the camera light goes off, so perhaps this is a Chrome bug.  I also discovered that if I use `chrome://settings/content` to change the microphone device to anything other than "Default", Chrome audio fails altogether.  And finally, I realized that using `element.src=undefined` resulted in Chrome attempting to load a resource and throwing a 404 so that's clearly not correct... so back to `element.src=''` on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up being my fault (yes, shocking).  Turns out I wasn't saving `localStream` correctly in the `onUserMediaSuccess` callback of `getUserMedia`... once that was set, Chrome is turning off the blinking recording icon.  That didn't explain the other anomalies, but it closes the main point of the question.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14366623/1916258

Answer (score 0):

I *just* got this working yesterday after trawling through the WebRTC specification. I don't know if this is the "right" way to do it, but I found that renegotiating the PeerConnection with a new offer after removing the stream did the trick.

```
var pc = peerConnections[socketId];
pc.removeStream(stream);
pc.createOffer( function(session_description) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(session_description);
  _socket.send(JSON.stringify({
    "eventName": "send_offer",
    "data":{
      "socketId": socketId,
      "sdp": session_description
      }
    }));
},
function(error) {},
defaultConstraints);
```

Comment: thanks for the post; i added to my close code above a `peerConnection.createOffer` just above the `peerConnection.close` line but it oddly seems to fail somehow without calling either the success callback or the fail callback, and doesn't throw an error either.  and unfortunately my little chrome tab recording icon is still blinking.  i'll keep working this angle and post back if i find anything, thanks.